# How to avoid accidentally implicitly referring to properties on the global object?

Tags: javascript, scope, with-statement

Is it possible to execute a block of code without the implicit `with(global)` context that all scripts seem to have by default? For example, in a browser, would there be any way to set up a script so that a line such as

```
const foo = location;
```

throws

> Uncaught ReferenceError: location is not defined

instead of accessing `window.location`, when `location` has not been declared first? Lacking that, is there a way that such an implicit reference could result in a warning of some sort? It can be a source of bugs when writing code (see below), so having a way to guard against it could be useful.

(Of course, due to ordinary scoping rules, it's possible to declare another variable with the same name using `const` or `let`, or within an inner block, to ensure that using that variable name references the new variable rather than the global property, but that's not the same thing.)

This may be similar to asking whether it's possible to stop referencing a property from within an *actual* `with` statement:

```
const obj = { prop: 'prop' };
with (obj) {
  // how to make referencing "prop" from somewhere within this block throw a ReferenceError
}
```

It's known that `with` should not be used in the first place, but unfortunately it seems we have no choice when it comes to the `with(global)`, which occasionally saves a few characters at the expense of confusing bugs which pop up somewhat frequently: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450783/javascript-function-close) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685364/boolean-variable-returns-as-string-from-javascript-function) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585775/simple-javascript-error-that-is-driving-me-insane) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334581/error-on-using-alert-in-javascript-property-alert-of-object-is-not-a-function) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844558/confirm-function-is-not-working). For example:

```js
var status = false;
if (status) {
  console.log('status is actually truthy!');
}
```

(the issue here: `window.status` is a reserved property - when assigned to, it coerces the assigned expression to a string)

These sorts of bugs are the same reason that explicit use of `with` is discouraged or prohibited, yet the implicit `with(global)` continues to cause issues, even in strict mode, so figuring out a way around it would be useful.

Comment: Is _"to ensure that using that variable name references the new variable rather than the global property, but that's not the same thing."_ a restriction to meet the requirement _"`// how to make referencing "prop" from somewhere within this block throw a ReferenceError`"_?

Comment: No, it's just not very useful - to use that method to *ensure* one doesn't ever accidentally implicitly refer to something on the global object, you would have to explicitly declare *lots and lots* of variables (and even then, referencing them wouldn't throw an error - it would be nice if referencing something that hasn't been explicitly declared as a standalone variable throws an error).

Comment: Use cases? "Controllable" "Proxy" scope? "Scope Observer"? Have you noted or tried any workarounds and considered edge cases to the code implemented at the answer during testing?

Comment: Yep, controllable scope - accidental references to global properties can cause bugs, so I'm hoping for ways to safeguard against that. (kind of like how strict mode throws errors when one tries to assign to a variable that doesn't exist) The answer is only a messy workaround, it doesn't even work in strict mode, but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I did think about using a real `Proxy` to allow one to reference outer variables that happened to be named the same as a window property without throwing an error, but it makes an already-weird situation a lot weirder for very little gain, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Even where the code achieves the requirement "intercepting" controller execution could produce unexpected results; just an example case re considering workarounds/edge case testing  `const o = Object
o.prop = 1; Object = void 0; with(o) { try {const x = Object || top.Object || self.Object || new ReferenceError(x); console.log(top.Object, self.Object, this.Object, x);} catch(e) {console.error(e)} try {console.log(Object.getOwnProperties(o));} catch(e) {console.error(e)}}` Getting and setting all properties of global should be possible. Can estimate use cases for "Scope Controller" concept.

Comment: FWIW have considered a similar concept [Why does .then() chained to Promise.resolve() allow const declaration to be reassigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380637/why-does-then-chained-to-promise-resolve-allow-const-declaration-to-be-reas)

Comment: This answer looks like it fits your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser/24660713#24660713

Comment: @CertainPerformance What is the actual use case for this? Are you executing (`eval`ing) foreign scripts and don't want them to access global variables? If you just want to guard your own code from mistakes, this is the job of a linter that will easily recognise usage of undeclared variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some things you need to consider before trying to answer this question.

For example, take the [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) constructor. It is a ["Standard built-in object"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).

[`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is part of the [`Window` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Obviously, you don't want `status` to refer to `window.status`, but do you want `Object` to refer to `window.Object`?

---

The solution to your problem of it not being able to be redefined is to use a IIFE, or a module, which should be what you are doing anyways.

```
(() => {
  var status = false;
  if (!status) {
    console.log('status is now false.');
  }
})();
```

And to prevent accidentally using global variables, I would just set up your linter to warn against it. Forcing it using a solution like `with (fake_global)` would not only have errors exclusively at run time, which might be not caught, but also be slower.

---

Specifically with ESLint, I can't seem to find a "good" solution. Enabling browser globals allows implicit reads.

I would suggest [no-implicit-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-globals) (As you shouldn't be polluting the global scope anyways, and it prevents the `var status` not defining anything problem), and also not enabling all browser globals, only, say, `window`, `document`, `console`, `setInterval`, etc., like you said in the comments.

Look at the [ESLint environments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) to see which ones you would like to enable. By default, things like `Object` and `Array` are in the global scope, but things like those listed above and `atob` are not.

To see the exact list of globals, they are defined by [this file in ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/caeb223c4f7b0b6fe35e5348ae0df4c6446b5bed/conf/environments.js) and [the `globals` NPM package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/master/globals.json). I would would pick from (a combination of) "es6", "worker" or "shared-node-browser".

The eslintrc file would have:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-implicit-globals": "error"
    },
    "globals": {
        "window": "readonly",
        "document": "readonly"
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": false,
        "es6": [true/false],
        "worker": [true/false],
        "shared-node-browser": [true/false]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, a script-writer may want to be able to keep referring to some global properties implicitly (like `window.undefined`, and perhaps `window.Object` as well). An IIFE helps (I mentioned this option in the question), but with it, it's still possible to accidentally reference global properties, eg `const someVar = location` and then later "Oops, I forgot to define `location` earlier in the block, this line is referring to `window.location`".

Comment: From the feedback on the question, a good comprehensive runtime solution looks to be slow, ugly, or hacky - **a linter *before* runtime sounds like the best solution by far**. Would you mind fleshing that out some? For example, to achieve this with ESLint, it looks like one would have to make sure the "browser" environment is *disabled* (else implicit references are permitted), while `window` is specified as a global variable.

Comment: We leave `browser: true` and then use `no-restricted-globals` to blacklist the global variables that have caused us problems. `"no-restricted-globals": ["error", "closed", "event", "fdescribe", "name", "length", "location", "parent", "top"]`

Answer (score 4):

If you're not in strict mode, one possibility is to iterate over the property names of the global (or `with`ed) object, and create another object from those properties, whose setters and getters all throw `ReferenceErrors`, and then nest your code in *another* `with` over that object. See comments in the code below.

This isn't a *nice* solution, but it's the only one I can think of:

```js
const makeObjWhosePropsThrow = inputObj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(inputObj)
  .reduce((a, propName) => {
    const doThrow = () => { throw new ReferenceError(propName + ' is not defined!'); };
    Object.defineProperty(a, propName, { get: doThrow, set: doThrow });
    return a;
  }, {});

// (using setTimeout so that console shows both this and the next error)
setTimeout(() => {
  const windowWhichThrows = makeObjWhosePropsThrow(window);
  with (windowWhichThrows) {
    /* Use an IIFE
     * so that variables with the same name declared with "var" inside
     * create a locally scoped variable
     * rather than try to reference the property, which would throw
     */
    (() => { 
      // Declaring any variable name will not throw:
      var alert = true;  // window.alert
      const open = true; // window.open
      
      // Referencing a property name without declaring it first will throw:
      const foo = location;
    })();
  }
});

const obj = { prop1: 'prop1' };
with (obj) {
  const inner = makeObjWhosePropsThrow(obj);
  with (inner) {
    // Referencing a property name without declaring it first will throw:
    console.log(prop1);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Caveats:

- This explicitly uses `with`, which is forbidden in strict mode
- This doesn't *exactly* escape the implicit `with(global)` scope, or the `with(obj)` scope: variables in the outer scope with the same name as a property will not be referenceable.
- `window` has a property `window`, which refers to `window`. `window.window === window`. So, referencing `window` inside the `with` will throw. Either explicitly exclude the `window` property, or save another reference to `window` first.

Comment: This is just an ugly hack I thought of while writing the question. It's not intended to be *the* answer, I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: Have you considered perhaps to run a linter on a piece of code as string and only execute it if it passes the linter check?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat simpler to implement than @CertainPerformance's answer, you can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to catch implicit access to everything except `window`. The only caveat is you can't run this in strict mode:

```js
const strictWindow = Object.create(
  new Proxy(window, {
    get (target, property) {
      if (typeof property !== 'string') return undefined
      console.log(`implicit access to ${property}`)
      throw new ReferenceError(`${property} is not defined`)
    }
  }),
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors({ window })
)

with (strictWindow) {
  try {
    const foo = location
  } catch (error) {
    window.console.log(error.toString())
  }

  // doesn't throw error
  const foo = window.location
}
```

Notice that even `console` has to have an explicit reference in order to not throw. If you want to add that as another exception, just modify `strictWindow` with another own property using

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors({ window, console })
```

In fact, there are [a lot of standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) you may want to add exceptions for, but that is beyond the scope of this answer (no pun intended).

In my opinion, the benefits this offers fall short of the benefits of running in strict mode. A much better solution is to use a properly configured linter that catches implicit references during development rather than at runtime in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *slightly* cleaner (YMMV) is to set getter traps (like you did), but in a worker so that you don't pollute your main global scope. I didn't need to use `with` though, so perhaps that is an improvement.

**Worker "Thread"**

```
//worker; foo.js
addEventListener('message', function ({ data }) {
  try {
    eval(`
      for (k in self) {
        Object.defineProperty(self, k, {
          get: function () {
            throw new ReferenceError(':(');
          }
        });
      }
      // code to execute
      ${data}
    `);
    postMessage('no error thrown ');
  } catch (e) {
    postMessage(`error thrown: ${e.message}`);
  }
});
```

**Main "Thread"**

```
var w = new Worker('./foo.js');
w.addEventListener('message', ({data}) => console.log(`response: ${data}`));
w.postMessage('const foo = location');
```

[image]

---

Another option that may be worth exploring is [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's goal is to prevent *implicit* accesses to global properties (`const foo = location` fails) while at the same time allowing *explicit* accesses (`const foo = self.location` works fine). The approach here prevents both.

Comment: I see. Yeah in that case you're right, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Cool, this makes me realize I had an implicit assumption that I shouldn't mutate the native `window`, but that's not necessarily required. Explicit references to the global object could be retained through a Proxy: https://jsfiddle.net/7t60Lu2b/ (inside a worker, if desired). Ugly and fragile, but doesn't require `with`. The worker method is similar to the linked answer by Ry- - deleted now, but you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/18f966d8994b7ecb0b6983fa001f9ff6) if you want.

Answer (score -3):

Just use `"use strict"`. More on [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

[image]

Comment: `b` is not a property of the global object, so `const a = b` will throw regardless of strict or sloppy mode. The question is about lines like `const a = location`, which will not throw, where `location` is a property on the global object, that one accidentally referred to.

Comment: `'use strict'` only works in the console if you put *all* code you want to run strictly *on the same line*, eg `'use strict'; ('a').b = 'c';` throws an error, but typing those into separate lines does not throw, because the second line is not strict.