# Javascript issue when using let

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, let

I have the below js for unit testing an error handler:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import deepClone from 'lodash.clonedeep';
import deepEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
import { spy } from 'sinon';
import errorHandler from './index';

function getValidError(constructor = SyntaxError) {
  let error = new constructor();
  error.status = 400;
  error.body = {};
  error.type = 'entity.parse.failed';
  return error;
}

describe('errorHandler', function() {
  let err;
  let req;
  let res;
  let next;
  let clonedRes;
  describe('When the error is not an instance of SyntaxError', function() {
    err = getValidError(Error);
    req = {};
    res = {};
    next = spy();
    clonedRes = deepClone(res);
    errorHandler(err, req, res, next);

    it('should not modify res', function() {
      assert(deepEqual(res, clonedRes));
    });

    it('should call next()', function() {
      assert(next.calledOnce);
    });
  });

  ...(#other test cases all similar to the first)

  describe('When the error is a SyntaxError, with a 400 status, has a `body` property set, and has type `entity.parse.failed`', function() {
    err = getValidError();
    req = {};
    let res = {
      status: spy(),
      set: spy(),
      json: spy()
    };
    let next = spy();
    errorHandler(err, req, res, next);

    it('should set res with a 400 status code', function() {
      assert(res.status.calledOnce);
      assert(res.status.calledWithExactly(400));
    });

    it('should set res with an application/json content-type header', function() {
      assert(res.set.calledOnce);
      assert(res.set.calledWithExactly('Content-Type', 'application/json'));
    });

    it('should set res.json with error code', function() {
      assert(res.json.calledOnce);
      assert(res.json.calledWithExactly({ message: 'Payload should be in JSON format' }));
    });
  });
});
```

Notice that I have `let` in front of `res`, `next` and `clonedRes` in the describe block for 'When the error is a SyntaxError...'.

Without the `let` in front of these, I get failures in my tests. I do not understand why I need to add the `let` for these again, but not for the `err` and `req` in that same block. Could anyone help me out with an explanation?

Comment: It's always a good pratice to explicitly declare your variable ( using `var` or `let`). Javascript is supposed to understand implicitly declared variable but it can run into problem, like in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strict mode (and in decently linted code in general), a variable must be declared before it's assigned to. Also, `const` and `let` variables must be declared *once* in a block, and no more. Re-declaring the `err` (or any other variable) which has already been declared will throw an error, which is why you should see `let <varname>` only once in your `describe('errorHandler'` function:

```js
const describe = cb => cb();

let something;
describe(() => {
  something = 'foo';
});
let something;
describe(() => {
  something = 'bar';
});
```

Further `describe`s *inside of* `describe('errorHandler'` already have scoped access to `err`.

Without declaring a variable first at all, assigning to it in sloppy mode will result in it being assigned to the global object, which is almost always undesirable and [can introduce bugs and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-run-code-without-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-object). For example:

```js
// Accidentally implicitly referencing window.status, which can only be a string:

status = false;
if (status) {
  console.log('status is actually truthy!');
}
```

That said, it's often a good idea to keep variables scoped as narrowly as possible - only assign to an outside variable when you *need* the value in the outer scope. Consider declaring the variables only inside of the `describe`s that assign to them, which has an additional bonus of allowing you to use `const` instead of `let`:

```
describe('When the error is not an instance of SyntaxError', function() {
  const err = getValidError(Error);
  const req = {};
  const res = {};
  const next = spy();
  const clonedRes = deepClone(res);
  errorHandler(err, req, res, next);
  // etc
});
// etc
describe('When the error is a SyntaxError, with a 400 status, has a `body` property set, and has type `entity.parse.failed`', function() {
  const err = getValidError();
  const req = {};
  const res = {
    status: spy(),
    set: spy(),
    json: spy()
  };
  const next = spy();
  // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is useful. I was basically trying to avoid having to type `const` everywhere. Why is it a bonus to use `const` rather than `let`?

Comment: It makes the code more readable when you *know* that a variable is not going to be reassigned. For example, consider `const foo = 'foo'; <30 lines of code> <do something with foo>` You *know* that `foo` will definitely be `'foo'` without having to carefully look through those 30 lines for any `foo = <somethingElse>`. Reassignment should be avoided when possible.