# Where do invalid variables go when using JavaScript's with(){} statement?

Tags: javascript, scope, internals, scope-chain

When using JavaScript's with statement, where do variables that have invalid names go?

```js
var o = {"@#$%":1,"test":2}

with(o){
  console.log(test)
  // Can't do this:
  //console.log(@#$%)
  // Was it not imported, or is it just inaccessible?
}
```

Can you reference the code in a JavaScript engine as well?

Comment: What happens to the invalid variables without the `with` statement? You can't write `o.@#$%` either.

Comment: FYI, [Use of the **with** statement is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: @Scaramouche I am aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a property is not a valid identifier, it can't be referenced like an identifier inside `with`. It's not inaccessible, but your only option is to look up the property on the original object manually, like normal:

```js
var o = {"@#$%":1,"test":2}

with(o){
  console.log(o['@#$%']);
}
```

This sort of issue is not exclusive to the deprecated `with` statement. It occurs with the global object as well. Just like a `with` statement [creates an object Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-with-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation), similarly, all code in a script is, in a sense, implicitly wrapped in a `with` for the global object (resulting in the global environment record).

So, for exactly the same reasons, when a property which can't be an identifier is on `window`, eg:

```js
window['###'] = 'foo';
```

There's no way to get to `foo` by using a standalone identifier without explicitly referencing `window` first (or use some other method to get to the global object).

(of course, just like with `with`, properties which *are* valid as identifiers on `window` can be referenced standalone - that's why we can, for example, reference `undefined` and `Array` instead of `window.undefined` and `window.Array`. This can [cause bugs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-avoid-accidentally-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-objec))

Comment: Thank you, great work in providing an analogy with the window object and referencing where to find further details in the ECMA Spec.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do variables […] go?

I think you have this backwards. A `with` statement doesn't create any variables (like a `var` declaration would), instead it changes the *scope* so that any identifier is looked up as a property on the object. Every time you access `xyz`, it looks `if ('xyz' in o) return o.xyz else …` - that's why `with` statements are so slow and deprecated in strict mode.

So there are no "variables that have invalid names" at all. If you used an invalid identifier in the first place, it would have thrown a syntax error and the code wouldn't even run.